# Cocos2d: Get data from file(sprites35.png) failed! when testing on device but working on the simulator

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-x

I tring to test my app in my iphone 5 device and im getting this error 
Note! this is working fine on the xcode and the iphone simulator:

```
Cocos2d: cocos2d: CCSpriteFrameCache: Trying to use file sprites35.png as texture
Cocos2d: Get data from file(sprites35.png) failed!
Cocos2d: cocos2d: CCSpriteFrameCache: Couldn't load texture
```

this is my simple code that load the files :

```
void GameLayer::loadImages()
{
    CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->addSpriteFramesWithFile("sprites35.plist");
    m_gameBatchNode  = CCSpriteBatchNode::create("sprites.png",200);
    this->addChild(m_gameBatchNode,2,kSSheet);
    m_background  = CCSprite::create("gride300_300.png");
    m_background->setPosition(ccp(m_winSize.width/2,m_winSize.height/2));  
    this->addChild(m_background,kGrid);

}
```

what im missing here ?

**UPDATE**
the answer is :
[How to Empty Caches and Clean All Targets Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4)

Comment: Hi, would you please paste your solution update as an answer and accept it, cleaning all project targets solved my problem as well.